# OneDrive convert PowerPoint pptx to ppsx

Tags: ms-office, office365, powerpoint, onedrive

Is there any api for OneDrive to convert pptx files to ppsx format?

I tried rename (actually copy) pptx file to ppsx using onedrive copy api
But simply renaming file from pptx to ppsx doesn't work
(IIRC this used to work before OOXML formats)
Idea is to open pptx file directly as slide show mode

Comment: Maybe related [start power point viewer in full screen (kiosk) mode](https://superuser.com/q/604367/506255) if you only need to control to automatically start in slideshow mode you should not need to convert your pptx files.

Comment: @Filburt actually files are stored on OneDrive and they are to be opened from browser using Office URI from an WebApp (Which is not working right now for me see [companion question for that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319162/office-uri-open-powerpoint-pptx-file-in-presentation-mode-directly-slide-show) any way thanks for responce)